# "Standalone" Android Apps with Python?

Tags: android, python, qpython

It's known you can run Python on Android with [QPython](http://qpython.com/), but first users have to download and install it on their phone.

Just wondering: is it possible to pack QPython dependencies together with "app" script creating a "standalone" PlayStore-ready `.apk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but you can create totally standalone apks with the graphical framework [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home), or specifically kivy's android build tools. They only directly support apps with a kivy gui, but this is easy to construct if you just want to run a simple script.

Alternatively, I think you actually only need to put your code in a kivy App class, which will run the script but then immediately exit if you don't define any graphics. Maybe this is exactly what you want.